# set value of a hidden form field in laravel admin

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-form, laravel-admin

I want to set a default value for a hidden form field in laravel 8.

```
$form->hidden("product.product_type")->value('1')->setDisplay(false);
```

Here after saving the form, the value is set as `null` and not `1`. What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you have to chain default function

> $form->hidden("product.product_type")->value('1')->setDisplay(false)->default('Any
> Value');

as per documentation here

https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/model-form-fields#Set%20default%20value